# How do I stop a Pmono?

Tags: supercollider

I read through the documentation of `Pmono` and must have read it wrong. From the following I inferred that the node `Pmono` creates would be deleted after the `Pmono` finishes:

"This node is created when entering a Pmono, and released when the Pmono terminates."

So I thought a `Pmono` like this:

```
p = Pmono(\default, \dur, 0.2, \freq, 400).play;
```

...would create a Synth that played for 0.2 seconds and then get released automatically. However, it keeps playing forever, which makes me wonder what the `\dur, 0.2` relates to.

How do I kill the `Pmono` when I don't want it anymore? Or possibly more to the point, is there a Pthing which means 'Create this monophonic synth, to which I can continue to send control data after it's started up, and which is released automatically at the end of the pattern'?

Edit: some more context of what I'm trying to do: I would like to be able to create an instance of an expensive effects synth, which I only want for a bar or so, which just automatically gets released after I've finished with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to understand is why it keeps playing forever rather than just 0.2. You can see what's going on if you run the `Pbind` equivalent:

```
 p = Pbind(\instrument, \default, \dur, 0.2, \freq, 400).play;
```

If you run this you don't just hear a single note, you hear the note being hit again and again forever, until you run

```
 p.stop;
```

So why is that? It's because all of the "values" specified are simple numbers or symbols (`\default ... 0.2 ... 400`), and these are always interpreted as meaning "continue forever or until something else stops us".

If you wanted Pbind to play just one note you would need to use at least one pattern in there which limits itself to just one item:

```
 p = Pbind(\instrument, \default, \dur, 0.2, \freq, Pseq([400], 1)).play;
```

So you can do the same thing with Pmono:

```
 p = Pmono(\default, \dur, 0.2, \freq, Pseq([400], 1)).play;
```

This has *exactly the same result* as the Pbind example, actually, but that's because it's playing only one note. We can make the difference a little bit clearer with these two-note examples:

```
 p = Pbind(\instrument, \default, \dur, 0.4, \freq, Pseq([400, 500], 1)).play;

 p = Pmono(\default, \dur, 0.4, \freq, Pseq([400, 500], 1)).play;
```

The first plays two separate notes, the second plays one with a pitch change halfway through.

So, note that your inference was correct - the node does get deleted after the Pmono terminates - but your Pmono was not terminating.

Comment: So the effective difference between `Pbind` and `Pmono` is that in the former, arrays are interpreted as being parallel messages (i.e. multichannel expansion), but in the latter, arrays are interpreted as being serial messages?

Comment: No, that's not the difference at all (sorry). The difference is that Pbind starts-and-stops one synth for every note (i.e. notes are completely separate sonically). Whereas Pmono starts a synth, and updates it with new control values for each new note, then stops the synth only when the entire pattern is finished. This way, notes can be "connected together" e.g. with portamento slides between the notes.